# retrieving the rows in the order of where clause values

Tags: sql, database, derby

Problem with the order of retrieving rows. I have a table called documentfiles in that i have three columns filename filepath num i have a query which retrieves filename and filepath with respect to the num 
here is my query

```
rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT filename from
                          documentfiles
                          where num  in
                                 (2167, 2156, 
                                  1677, 2149,
                                  1946,1511
                                 ) "
                  );
```

the problem here i am facing is the query retrieving rows in the ascending order of num that is retrieving in this order

> `1511 1677 1946 2149 2151 2156 2167 2526 2527 2612 2887 2890 2894 2895 3665 6254 6258 6920 7001 7013 7071 7072 7074 7100`

but i want in this order

> `2167, 2156, 1677, 7074, 2149, 7100, 7072, 2890, 2527, 2526, 1946, 1511, 7071, 7013, 7001, 6920, 6258, 6254, 3665, 2895, 2894, 2887, 2612, 2151`

well i have stored num with values in ascending order
 `1511 1677 1946 2149 2151 2156 2167 2526 2527 2612 2887 2890 2894 2895 3665 6254 6258 6920 7001 7013 7071 7072 7074 7100` 
not in this order

> 2167, 2156, 1677, 2149, 1946, 1511

so how do i achieve this is that possible,

any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: There's a simple rule with SQL. Unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, the system is free to return the results in whatever order is most convenient for it to process the rest of the query.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

Adapt the query to:

```
SELECT filename 
from documentfiles 
where num in (2167, 2156, 1677,2149,1946,1511)
order by case when num = 2167 then 1
              when num = 2156 then 2
              when num = 1677 then 3
              when num = 2149 then 4
              when num = 1946 then 5
              when num = 1511 then 6
         end
```

If it is a generated script you don't care how many you put, as it will be fairly simple to construct your query. If it is not generated, then you have to put it by hand.

I also might suggest that you make a sp out of it, and call it with a TVP (table valued parameter) with 2 columns (num,crt). So your query will change like:

```
SELECT filename 
from documentfiles df
join tvp 
  on df.num=tvp.num
order by crt
```

Comment: it is too much troublesome just for explanation i added few values but i actually have these values 2167, 2156, 1677, 7074, 2149, 7100, 7072, 2890, 2527, 2526, 1946, 1511, 7071, 7013, 7001, 6920, 6258, 6254, 3665, 2895, 2894, 2887, 2612, 2151

Comment: @user2318813 you need it in descending order or in a specific order..!

Comment: thanks for your reply well i need it in specific order that is the order i specified

Comment: @user2318813 do you have anyother columns in the table?? and can you please provide the reason why do you need it in the specific order?? so that we can write the query accordingly

Comment: well basically i'm developing one desktop search engine where user enters a keyword and i retrieve the the filename and filepath with respect to the keyword, i have store keywords with file number in document table and and filename and filepath with file number in documentfiles , so when the user enters keyword i retrieve all the files numbers which contain that keyword and then put numbers in one list and then later i use that list to access filename and filepath from the documentfiles, so here list contains the specific ordererd file number values

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL:

```
with numbers (num, sort_order) as (
  values (2167,1), (2156,2), (1677,3), (2149,4), (1946,5), (1511, 6)
)
select filename 
from documentfiles d 
  join numbers n on d.num = n.num
order by n.sort_order
```

Comment: thanks for your reply well this definitely works but i have too many values not just 6 values so what to do in that case

Comment: @user2318813: that will work for many values just as well. You still haven't answered which DBMS you are using. Any other option will be highly DBMS specific

Comment: well thanks for your answer i can try out with this, BTW i'm using derby database.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE numbers
(
    ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
    number int
)

CREATE PROCEDURE insertnumbers
@number int
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (@number);
END
```

Now you add comma on beginning

```
,2167, 2156, 1677, 7074, 2149, 7100,
7072, 2890, 2527, 2526, 1946, 1511,
7071, 7013, 7001, 6920, 6258, 6254,
3665, 2895, 2894, 2887, 2612, 2151
```

and then you use notepad and SEARCH AND REPLACE

search: `,`
replace: `; EXEC insertnumbers`

Then you remove first `;` and you can insert numbers. Then you INNER JOIN table filename with table numbers ON filename.filenumber = numbers.number and ORDER BY numbers.ID.

Comment: i tried that, the problem i face there is i have stored num with values in ascending order 1511,1677,1946,2149,2156,2167 not in this order 2167, 2156, 1677, 2149, 1946, 1511 so the result is still the same this no change

Comment: In my case it works (I used my command in my test database) so I do not know how I can help you. Maybe we wait for another answers.

Comment: @user3162968 - the OP wants the row with `num` `1677` to appear after the row with `2156` and before the row with `2149`. Neither sorting on `num` ascending nor descending will produce such a result.